# Access nested JSON object without specifying key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, nested, nested-lists

I decided to learn more on JavaScript looping and mapping functions by doing nested objects/arrays. Now I stumbled into a problem which is somewhat similar to this but far more complicated.

[Accessing elements of JSON object without knowing the key names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BRNN.png)

here's my JSON:

```
"employees": {
    "Gill Bates": {
        "position": "Software Engineer",
        "office": "Tokyo, Japan"
    },
    "Jebron Lames": {
        "position": "Full-stack Developer",
        "office": "Manila, Philippines"
    }
}
```

and my **accessJson** function which is the famous solution for nested JSON objects:

```js
function accessJson(obj) {
  const result = [];
  for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result.push(toArray(value));
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The code is working perfectly fine in accessing the JSON object. But the problem is that I'm getting a return which looks like this:

[image]

In which I needed to write another function again in order to trim and combine those characters just to get every employees position. Is there a way I can get every employees position without specifying their name? Like a one line variable declaration(not working) like this:

```js
let position = Object.keys(employees)[0].position;
```

In which I can insert it inside my loop so I can delete my existing **accessJson** function and lessen my code.

EDIT:

Please don't mark my question as a duplicate one. I think I already mentioned it above that my code is fine and perfectly working. What I wanted to get feedback is, can we optimize my code into a one line declaration so we can get rid of **accessJson** function and avoid the creation of another function that will trim and combine those characters just to get every employees position.

My question and **accessJson** function is similar to this:

[How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Your `obj` variable is a JSON string. You need to parse it to make it an object: `obj = JSON.parse(obj);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1169519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "employees": {
      "Gill Bates": {
          "position": "Software Engineer",
          "office": "Tokyo, Japan"
      },
      "Jebron Lames": {
          "position": "Full-stack Developer",
          "office": "Manila, Philippines"
      }
  }
};

const { employees } = data;

const extract = (p) => Object.keys(employees).map(name => employees[name][p]);

console.log('get every employees position', extract('position'));
console.log('get every employees office', extract('office'));
```